# Client behind reverse proxy like nginx

Tags: nginx

As my tcpclient is behind nginx. 
My idea is to have backend tcpclient, authenticate the external server.

Finally, i had this configuration:

```
#secured TCP part
stream {
log_format main '$remote_addr - - [$time_local] protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time "$upstream_addr"';
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:10515 ;
proxy_pass REALIP:REALPORT;
proxy_ssl on;
#server side authentication (client verifying server's certificate)
proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
proxy_ssl_certificate /f0/client.crt;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key /f0/client.key;
access_log /var/log/nginx.tcp1.access.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx.tcp1.error.log debug;
#The trusted CA certificates in the file named by the proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate directive are used to verify the certificate on the ups
tream
proxy_ssl_verify on;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /f0/client_ca.crt;
proxy_ssl_verify_depth 1;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
proxy_ssl_name localhost;
ssl_session_timeout 4h;
ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#proxy_ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-A
ES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
proxy_ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH
+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-R
SA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:D
HE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA";
#ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1:secp384r1;
#ssl_session_tickets off;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
}
```

Can you please authenticate the above configuration and pls let me know, if I am doing right way of verifying the peer. 
If yes, my other question:
Is there a way, we can give peer certificate(public key) rather than its CA and verify.
Pls clarify

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The question looks obvious as it doesn't mention any specific aspects (apart from TLS).

Please visit the following to get a good start:

> https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/
>   https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/

Quoting simple example configuration from the above sources:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     12345;
        #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the "stream_backend" upstream group
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
    }
    server {
        listen     12346;
        #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the specified server
        proxy_pass backend.example.com:12346;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  But when, I have attempted as below, still dont see properly working.

Comment: If there are no traces from remote server wireshark, then it is likely that the outgoing connection from your network/machine is failing.
What do the local wireshark say?
Have you checked if the proxy_bind to internal address is working?

Comment: Hi, I got something working. But would need some authentication/clarification. Can you pls help.

Comment: If the answer solved the issue or clears how to solve the issue. Click on green tick to mark it as accepted answer. This is helpful for others.